# Result of function, as value in object

Tags: javascript

Is possible to obtain in **sum** result of a function ? Not function itself, just result.

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

let object = {
    dummy: 'dummy text',
    sum: function () {
        a + b
    },
}

console.log(object) // { dummy: 'dummy text', sum: [Function: sum] }
```

**I want to obtain : { dummy: 'dummy text', sum: 3 }**
I don't want to use an external function

Comment: why not: sum: a + b

Comment: You would need to execute the function.  For example: `console.log({ dummy: object.dummy, sum: object.sum() });`  For a more generic approach, you'd likely need to write some function (potentially recursive if you need to support larger and more complex objects) which iterates the properties of an object, checks if the property is a function, and executes that function.  Which will get very complex once your functions accept arguments.  Overall I guess it's not entirely clear what the goal/need is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an IIFE if you want to assign the result of a function invocation to `sum`

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

let object = {
  dummy: 'dummy text',
  sum: (function () {
    return a + b;
  })(),
};

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple static value, you could simply assign `a + b` as the value for `sum`. Otherwise you'd need to invoke `sum` method call.

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

let object = {
    dummy: 'dummy text',
    sum: a + b,
}

console.log(object) // { dummy: 'dummy text', sum: 3 }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but I need to keep the function. In fact, in function will be multiple lines of code, but I need to keep all code stick to sum.  Object itself is huge, and I would like the result of the function to be next to sum, for a better visibility in the code. I have no idea if what I want is possible, but I said to ask anyway

Comment: Understood. You could consider separating the function outside the object and then invoke the call inside the object—as mentioned in another answer. A more detailed context might be helpful to get a better answer in this case. What the function does, how they're handled, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute the function instead of initializing it.

This can be done by **instantiating** the function before and then call it when creating the object.

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

const sum = (a, b) => a + b

let object = {
    dummy: 'dummy text',
    sum: sum(a, b)
}

console.log(object)
```